# Querying IQueryable completely decoupled from ORM?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, orm, iqueryable

I may be completely misunderstanding what happens under the hood of an IQueryable, so if I'm wrong, I welcome correction.

I have a log table in my database that I want to view on a front end web application using a Kendo UI table.

These javascript components are really slick; they can target and limit the data coming over the connection based off of many dimensions... for example, I can get the top 100 records organized by log date, filtered for DEBUG or INFO where the user was "Joe User".

This works against an `IEnumerable<LogEntry>` object just fine... but there's a lot of `LogEntry` objects in the table, and I think that this should be very poorly performing as the logs table continues to grow.

I want to implement a service like this:

```
public interface ILogBrowsingService
{
    IQueryable<LogEntry> Logs { get; }
}
```

... with a concrete implementation in another assembly using an ORM (EF, NHibernate, Telerik DataAccess, haven't decided) that will allow offloading some (hopefully most) of the heavy lifting of the query to the database server.  I would basically be running the query against the exposed IQueryable in the service... however, I think I will quickly run into a problem, as this service will be running under its own service-specific data context, and its own Linq-To-X implementation.  I believe I will experience issues with this implementation, dealing with database context life cycles and IQueryable support and whatnot.

I was playing with the idea of capturing the "query" against a generic `IQueryable<LogEntry>` and passing it as an argument into the service to be replayed against the concrete implementation, but I have no idea how I would do that, but something along these lines:

```
public interface ILogBrowsingService
{
    IList<LogEntry> GetLogEntryQueryResults(IQuery<LogEntry> query);
}
```

I have no idea what an `IQuery<LogEntry>` would look like.

I really don't want to try and write a service/ repository pattern that will incorporate the multiple permutations of searchability for this table.  Am I imagining a problem where there is none, or is there a "proper" way to accomplish what I am trying to do, completely agnostic to the ORM backend?

Comment: Just don't use IQueryable. Return an IEnumerable and **never** tell to a repository **how** to do something. Just ask for things to be done. The repo will know how to use EF and others to return the entities. Keep things simple and pass a specific criteria(a simple object) for a specific query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this pattern called query object pattern which I believe is similar to what you are trying to achieve here. The pattern does not automatically record the queries and replays them for you but it lets you write queries in a way that they can be replayed and also avoids the side-effects of a pattern like repository.

We would being with defining an interface `IQuery<T>` as below

```
public interface IQuery<T> where T : EntityBase<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Run(IQueryable<T> queryable);
}
```

You can ignore the `where` constraint if you do not have a common entity base kind of implementation.

We would then have a very specific implementation of this interface depending on what are we querying. For instance, we can implement a query to fetch log entries depending on whether they are DEBUG, INFO or ERROR

```
public class LogEntriesByTypeQuery : IQuery<LogEntry>
{
    private readonly int type;

    public LogEntriesByTypeQuery(string type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public IEnumerable<LogEntry> Run(IQueryable<LogEntry> logEntries)
    {
        return (from e in logEntries
            where e.Type == type
            select e).ToList();
    }
}
```

We can now write very specific queries depending on what do we want to fetch from database. You can either combine multiple filter criteria or write a separate query for each. Unlike specification pattern this pattern would not give you an ability to combine multiple different queries together.

We then need something to run this query. A `QueryRunner` can be handy

```
public class QueryRunner : IRunQuery
{
    private readonly ISession session;

    public QueryRunner(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Run<T>(IQuery<T> query) where T : EntityBase<T>
    {
        return query.Run(session.Query<T>());
    }
}
```

In your service class, you can take a dependency on `IRunQuery` (if you are using dependency injection) and create an instance of the query object that you want to execute and pass it into `Run` method of `IRunQuery` instance.

This may not be perfect for your situation but you can play around with this pattern to see if it takes you in anywhere.